# EF Fluent API for hierarchical data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to store hierarchical data in the database and need help how to configure the model.
There is also a set of hierarchical data per user.
After the data has been stored in the database, it is changed very rarely.

The database, I plan to use are as follows:

```
User
    Id          int


TreeEntity
    Id          int
    UserId      int
    ParentId    int
```

`TreeEntity.UserId` reference to `User.Id` 
`TreeEntity.ParentId` reference to `TreeEntity.Id`. If `ParentId` is unset, it is the root in the tree.

I've thought about trying to configure EF so that the data is mapped to the following classes

```
User
    // All TreeEntity that have TreeEntity.UserId==User.Id
    // Desirable, but not necessary
    //   ICollection<TreeEntity>        AllEntitiesForUser{get; set;}

    // The roots of the tree for this User. 
    // All TreeEntity that have TreeEntity.UserId==User.Id and TreeEntity.Parent==0
    ICollection<TreeEntity>     Tree {get;set;}

TreeEntity
    // Reference to the User 
    User                        User {get;set;}
    // Reference to the parent
    TreeEntity                  Parent {get;set;}
    // List of all children
    ICollection<TreeEntity>     Children {get;set;}
```

What I have succeeded so far are as follows

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(d => d.Tree)
    .WithRequired(d => d.User);

modelBuilder.Entity<TreeEntity>()
    .HasMany(d => d.Children)
    .WithOptional(d => d.Parent);
```

This is obviously not correct, but I do not really know how I should proceed. If that's even possible?

Comment: I don't really see anything abnormal in your code. Are you getting a specific error or something?

Comment: Inside the `User` entity, you should have only one `ICollection<TreeEntity>`. It will contain all the user related items regardless of the `ParentId` - EF cannot do the filtering you have in mind.

Comment: I suspected that it could not do so as I wanted. It is aceptabelt removing AllEntitiesForUser. But just a list of all TreeEntity makes it difficult to work with it as a hirakisk tree structure.

If I have a TreeEntity I want to be able to get a list of all its children.